# spring-boot application.properties question -bug

Tags: java, spring-boot

there are three files in application demo ,but the result is wrong return ,
 name is correct ,but the pwd return my  project directory   why  ? a  bug ? or  pwd is  keyword ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8vCj.jpg)

1.application.properties：

```
name="Spring Boot"
pwd="love Spring boot"
```

2.SpringController :

```
@RestController
public class SpringController {
    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;
    @Value("${pwd}")
    private  String pwd;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String see(){
        return name+","+pwd;
    }

}
```

3.DemoApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try changing **pwd** to anything else? pwd is an ancient unix command that returns the current directory.

Comment: Since this is your first post, just let me give you an advice. In your question you linked an external image just to show what's going on. Sometimes it is better to include the expected output along with the wrong, it will make it easier to other users understand your issue.

Comment: thanks for your advices  very much !    I change  pwd to other  word , it is sure correct result .  only the  pwd  return the directory . So  unix commands are keyword in  spring-boot  ? right? .   if someone use wrong name variable name like unix command  in project's properties  ,it's  risk ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring-boot resolves properties from a [variety of sources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config), each source has a different priority.

One of the sources is environment variables, they have a higher priority than `application.properties` files.

Most UNIX shells set the environment variable `pwd` to be the current working directory, this is why it is replacing your configured value.

Simplest solution is to use a better more specific name for your property.